# Invariance property of MLE: what is the MLE of $\theta^2$ of normal, $\bar{X}^2$?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, point-estimation

Invariance property of MLE:  if $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE of $\theta$, then for any function $f(\theta)$, the MLE of $f(\theta)$ is $f(\hat{\theta})$.

Also, $f$ must be a one-to-one function.

The book says, "For example, to estimate ${\theta}^2$, the square of a normal mean, the mapping is not one-to-one."  So, we can't use invariance property.

But then, it proves the property and says, "we now see that MLE of $\theta^2$, the square of a normal mean is $\bar{x}^2$".

This seems self-contradicting, we are squaring $\bar{x}$, but square of anything is not one-to-one, what am I reading wrong here?  Thanks!

source: *Casella & Berger "Statistical Inference"*

Comment: "*Also, f must be a one-to-one function.*" -- [must it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Functional_invariance)? Why?

Answer (score 19):

That's not exactly what Casella and Berger say. They recognize (page 319) that when the transformation is one-to-one the **proof** of the invariance property is very simple. But then they extend the invariance property to arbitrary transformations of the parameters introducing an *induced likelihood function* on page 320. Theorem 7.2.10 on the same page gives the proof of the extended property. Hence, no contradiction here.

Answer (score 11):

From page 350 of ["Probability and Statistical Inference"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824703790):

[image]

(Note: This Theorem can be found on pg. 320 and labeled as 7.2.10 in the second edition.)