# If $X_1 \sim \text{binom}(p_1,n_1)$ and $X_2 \sim \text{binom}(p_2,n_2)$, how to prove that the MLE of $p = p_1 - p_2$ is $\hat{p}_1 - \hat{p}_2$?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, random-variable, binomial-distribution, invariance

Suppose $X_1 \sim \text{binom}(p_1,n_1)$ and $X_2 \sim \text{binom}(p_2,n_2)$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, and let $p = p_1 - p_2$. How can I prove that $\hat{p} = \hat{p}_1 - \hat{p}_2$? (Here, $\hat{\theta}$ denotes the MLE of $\theta$.) Initially, I tried to calculate the distribution of $X_1 + X_2$, but this turned out to be quite messy: Letting $Y = X_1 + X_2$, I found that for $y = 0,1,\ldots,n_1 + n_1$,
\begin{align*}
   P(Y = y) &= P(X_1 + X_2 = y) \\[4pt]
            &= \sum_{x=0}^{n_1} P(X_1 + X_2 = y|X_1 = x)P(X_1 = x) \\[4pt]
            &= \sum_{x=0}^{n_1} P(x + X_2 = y) P(X_1 = x) \\[4pt]
            &= \sum_{x=0}^{n_1} P(X_2 = y - x) P(X_1 = x) \\[4pt]
            &= \sum_{x=0}^{n_1} {n_2 \choose y - x} p_2^{y-x} (1-p_2)^{n_2 - (y-x)} {n \choose n_1} p_1^{x} (1-p_1)^{n_1 - x}
\end{align*}
At this point I couldn't really recognize $Y$ as having a familiar distribution. Also, it's not clear to me if the likelihood function for $Y$ depends on $p_1$ and $p_2$ only through the difference $p = p_1 - p_2$, so I'm not clear on how to obtain the MLE for $p$.

I came across a [post from 2015](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141633/mle-of-sum-of-two-binomials) on the same question, but it didn't have an answer. Also, one of the commenters on that post linked to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77573/invariance-property-of-mle-what-is-the-mle-of-theta2-of-normal-barx2) on the invariance property of the MLE:

> If $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE of $\theta$, then for any function $\tau(\theta)$, the MLE of $\tau(\theta)$ is $\tau(\hat{\theta})$.

(I'm quoting Theorem 7.2.10 of Casella and Berger's *Statistical Inference*.) However, I do not see how this particular theorem applies to my question, since I'm interested in the MLE of a function of *two* parameters associated with *two* independent random variables. Now if there was an invariance theorem that said given independent random variables $X_1 \sim f(x_1|\theta_1)$ and $X_2 \sim g(x_2|\theta_2)$, we have $\widehat{\tau(\theta_1,\theta_2)} = \tau(\hat{\theta}_1,\hat{\theta}_2)$, then I would agree that $\hat{p} = \hat{p}_1 - \hat{p}_2$, but I don't believe that this is implied by the above theorem...Does such an invariance theorem exist? If not, how should I go about finding the MLE of $p$?

Comment: The parameter $\theta$ can be multivariate and the invariance property still holds!

Comment: The invariance property ultimately is trivial: it reflects the fact that *how you name the arguments of a function* has no effect on *what the values of that function are.*  Consequently, once you have found the extrema of a function (such as the likelihood), you can freely rename the arguments of (*i.e.*, reparameterize) that function.

Comment: @jbowman: Thanks! If only I had read the very next page of Casella and Burger: "The invariance property of MLEs also holds in the multivariate case. There is nothing in the proof of Theorem 7.2.10 that precludes $\theta$ from being a vector. If the MLE of $(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_k)$ is $(\hat{\theta}_1,\ldots,\hat{\theta}_k)$, then the MLE of $\tau(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_k)$ is $\tau(\hat{\theta}_1,\ldots,\hat{\theta}_k)$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you how the invariance property of the MLE applies to this case.  Consider the joint distribution of the two random variables, which depends on the parameter vector $\mathbf{p} = (p_1,p_2)$.  Suppose you find the MLE of this parameter vector via the joint distribution, and let's denote this MLE as:

$$\hat{\mathbf{p}}_\text{MLE} = (\hat{p}_1, \hat{p}_2).$$

Now, let's define the function $\tau$ so that $\tau(a,b) = a-b$.  Applying this function to both the underlying parameter vector, and its MLE we get:

$$\begin{align}
\tau(\mathbf{p})
= \tau(p_1, p_2) 
&= p_1 - p_2, \\[6pt]
\tau(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_\text{MLE})
= \tau(\hat{p}_1, \hat{p}_2) 
&= \hat{p}_1 - \hat{p}_2. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Now, the invariance property of the MLE says that the MLE of $\tau(\mathbf{p})$ is $\tau(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_\text{MLE})$, which is equivalent to saying that the MLE of $p_1 - p_2$ is $\hat{p}_1 - \hat{p}_2$.  (Note that your broader assertion that the joint distribution depends on $\mathbf{p}$ only through $p_1-p_2$ is false.)

Comment: Thank you! Somehow it hadn't immediately occurred to me that the invariance property still holds when $\theta$ is a vector.