# Maximum likelihood is not re-parametrization invariant. So how can one justify using it?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, frequentist

There is something that is confusing me about max-likelihood estimators. Suppose my I have some data and the likelihood under a parameter $\mu$ is

$$
L(D|\mu) = e^{-(.7-\mu)^2}
$$

which is recognizable as the likelihood of Gaussian upto scaling. Now my max likelihood estimator will give me $\mu=.7$.

Now suppose I didn't know that and instead was working with a parameter $t$ such that $\mu=\sin(t)$. Also suppose all this were numerical and so I wouldn't immediately see how silly the following likelihood looks like

$$
L(D|t) = e^{-(.7-\sin(t))^2}
$$

Now I would solve for the max likelihood and get additional solutions. To help see this I plot it below.

[image]

So from this point of view max-likelihood seems like a silly thing to do as it is **not re-parametrization invariant**. What am I missing?

Note that a Bayesian analysis would naturally take care of this since the likelihoods would always come with a measure

$$
L(D|\mu) P(\mu) d\mu = L(D|\mu(t)) P(\mu(t)) \frac{d\mu}{dt} dt
$$

**Added part after responses and comments (added on 3/16/2018)**

I realized later that my example above is not a good one because the two maxima in $t_1,t_2$ correspond to $.7=\sin(t_1)=\sin(t_2)$. So they are identifying the same point. I have kept the above for the discussion and responses below to make sense. However, I think the following is a better example of the issue I am trying to figure out.

Take

$$
L(D|\mu) = e^{-(a-\mu)^2}
$$

Now suppose I reparameterize $\mu=\mu(t)$ then do a max-likelihood with respect to $t$ I get

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu} \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t}
$$

If I want a maxima at a location other than from the one I get from maximizing with respect to $\mu$ I require

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu} \ne 0
$$

and

$$
\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t} =0, \qquad 
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu} \frac{\partial^2 \mu}{\partial t^2} < 0
$$

Thus, I can take a simple example

$$
\mu = b - (a-b)t^2+t^3
$$

I plot the results below. We can clearly see that $\mu=a$ is the global maxima (and only one when maximizing with respect to $\mu$) but we also have another local maxima at $t=0$ when we maximizing with respect to $t$.

[image]

Note the map $\mu(t)$ is not bijective but I do not see why it has to be. Also, at least in this example, the global maxima will always be the one at $\mu=a$ but from a frequentist point of view wouldn't I be oblidged to take some kind of weighted average of 1/1.6 of $\mu=a$ and .6/1.6 of $\mu=b$ (that corresponds to $t=0$) if I completely worked in the $t$ space?

Comment: On the contrary, the solution *is* invariant.  The correct formulation is that all the values $t$ which minimize $L(\mu(t))$ correspond to values of $\mu$ that minimize $L(\mu)$--which ought to be obvious from the notation alone.  For this result to hold, it doesn't matter whether $\mu$ is invertible, one-to-one, continuous, or anything else, because in the end all we're discussing is how to *name* the distribution(s) for which the likelihood is largest.  "A rose by any other name smells just as sweet."

Comment: I had to edit as my example was not good. New example is $L=e^{-(a-\mu)^2}$ and $\mu=b-(a-b) t^2 + t^3$. This gives an additional 'local' maxima at $t=0$. The likelihood is not bimodal so shouldn't one take weighted average? If so this would make the solution not invariant.

Comment: @whuber I do agree that since likelihood is a scalar, the global maxima is invariant under reparameterization just like a rose with another name smells just as sweet. I was talking more about the possibility of generating several local maxima and then justifying not taking the weighted average.

Comment: No average would necessarily make any sense at all, because in the end you are describing *distributions* rather than numbers.  In your many-to-one transformation, you ought to be "averaging" the same distribution with itself--because all the maxima correspond to the same distribution--but the average of the numerical "names" you assigned these distributions would be meaningless.

Comment: @whuber What about this example: We want to do a maximum likelihood estimate for a multinomial distribution for 4 classes and the parameters are $\{P_i\}$, we see $N$ objects and  $k_i$ object of each class, then the ML estimate of  $P_i$ is $\frac{k_i}{N}$, whereas now I do the following reparameterisation: $P_1 =x^2$, $P_2 =xy$,$P_3 =xz$ and $P_4 =yz$. Now, the ML estimates for $x,y$ and $z$ will not be the one that maximises ML for if $P_i's$ were not parameterised. Is my question clear ? I believe there must be some condition on the parameterisation ?

Comment: @SagarM What are your estimates of $(x,y,z)$? Although the ML solution in terms of these variables is usually not unique (because they aren't true parameters without further restrictions), one solution I obtain is $\hat x=\sqrt{k_1/N},$ $\hat z=\sqrt{k_1/N}(k_2+k_4)/(k_1+k_3),$ and $\hat y=(k_2/N+k_3/N)\sqrt{N}/k_1-\hat z.$ Indeed, I cannot understand what you mean by "$P_i$'s not parameterized," given you have stated they *are* parameters.

Comment: @whuber I meant that the ML value of $\{P_i\}$ when they are parameterised over $x,y$ and $z$ is not the same value that you get when $P_i$'s are not parameterised and ML is done w.r.t $\{P_i\}$. If I may add, what do you mean by they are not real parameters ? and I believe putting $x^2+xy+xz+yz=1$ should give us unique solutions ?

Comment: @SagarM I'm afraid you will have to exhibit a specific example of what you're talking about, because as far as I can tell you're asserting a mathematical impossibility.  The reason $(x,y,z)$ are not parameters is that they are redundant.  For instance, $(x,y,z)$ and $(-x,-y,-z)$ determine the same $P_i.$

Comment: I ll add it as a detailed question and link it here, thanks for the prompt replies !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at your graph, it appears that $\hat{t} \in \{0.7753975, 2.346194\}$ is a pretty reasonable guess at the MLE(s) of $t$.  Running those values through the $\sin$ function to get back to $\mu$ results in $\hat{\mu} = \{0.7, 0.7\}$ or $0.7$, just as it should.  So, there is no disagreement between the MLE of $\mu$ and the MLE(s) of $t$.

What is happening is that you have created a map from $\mu \to t$ that is not 1-1.  In this case, the true value of $\mu$ maps to multiple values of $t$, so not surprisingly you will have multiple maxima when working with $t$.  Note, however, that this would be the same if you were doing a Bayesian analysis, unless your prior restricted $t$ to the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ or some such.  If you did so, for comparability, you should restrict the range of the MLE of $t$ to the same range, in which case you won't get multiple maxima for the likelihood function any more.

ETA:  In retrospect I focused too much on explanation-by-example and not enough on the underlying principle.  One can hardly do better than @whuber's comment in response to the OP in this regard.

In general, if you have a parameter $\theta$ and an associated MLE $\hat{\theta}$, and you construct a function $\theta = f(t)$, you've effectively created an alternate parameter $t$.  The MLE of $t$, label it $\hat{t}$, will be those values of $t$ such that $f(t) = \hat{\theta}$, i.e., $f(\hat{t}) = \hat{\theta}$.

Comment: I agree that my example is not quite what I expected it to be. I realized it on the way back home. A better example is $\mu=b-t^2+t^3$. Here we get maxima for $t$ that do not map to $\mu=.7$ (depending on $b$). Nevertheless, it is also not bijective.

Comment: I don't see why the parametrization has to be bijective. In fact, I am not asking which parameterizations can be done to give the same answer, I am asking why maximum likelihood is used when it is not re-parameterization invariant.

Comment: Some of my best thinking is done in rush hour traffic... Can you come up with a $\mu$, $b$ and $t$ for which $\mu = b - t^2 + t^3$ results in different values for the likelihood function when you plug $\mu$ in than when you plug $b - t^2 + t^3$ in in place of $\mu$?  I'm guessing not... see @whuber's comment above.

Comment: My point about the not 1-1 nature of your function isn't that it doesn't work at all, it's that that is what is responsible for the multimodality of the likelihood function for $t$ (well that and that the function isn't 1-1 at $\mu$, which is clearly more restrictive.)

Comment: I edited to include the aforementioned example. I took $\mu= b- (a-b) t^2 + t^3$. Then as long as $a \ne b$ there is an additional 'local' maxima at $t=0 (\mu=b)$. Even though its a local maxima, since its height is comparable, the max-likelihood should be a weighted average of $\mu=a,b$ (I am guessing that is what is done for bimodal max-likelihood).

Comment: Your guess is clever but wrong :)  The maximum likelihood estimate is any from the collection of values that maximize the likelihood, not an average thereof.  Looking at your modified function, if $b = \mu$, then $t = 0$ and  $t = (a-b)$ both maximize the likelihood, so, as with your initial example, there are two values, both of which are the MLEs, and for exactly the same reason as in your initial example: the map from $\mu \to t$ is not 1-1.

Comment: I understand its not bijective. It will be bijective when $a=b$ and then I will not have two local maxima. However, I don't understand WHY the map needs to bijective (as in what axiom or law forbids it) and for a bimodal likelihood, what is the prescription? 

Also notice, the way I have written things it seems "obvious" $\mu$ is the correct variable. However, that is only because of aesthetics. A priori, I don't see a reason to say one is more true than the other. In that case, the question is not which parametrization give the same answer but instead which is the "correct" answer.

Comment: Nobody has said it has to be bijective!  It doesn't have to be bijective!  Look at the last paragraph in my answer, it will answer your question about multimodal likelihoods.  And as for which parameterization is "right", they are all equally right.  Which one is most useful depends on the questions being addressed by the analysis.

Comment: So the bottom line as @whuber pointed out is that MLE does not care about local maxima but only global ones.

Comment: Correct, with the addenda that 1) it's OK to have an MLE with multiple possible values that maximize the likelihood and 2) reparameterization of the likelihood function can be done to make the parameters fit the objectives of the analysis.

Answer (score 2):

As my previous answer wasn't completely clear about the need for bijectivness
or not (one could argue my answer was just plain wrong). I did some
research about the whole reparametrizing thing and here is what I
found out. Both @whuber and @jbowman touch upon some of the same things.

#### Theory

So, in theory, the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}$ of
the likelihood function $L\left(\theta\right)$, is invariant to re-parametrization.
So, say you have some known function $g$, which re-parametrizes $\theta$
into $\lambda=g(\theta)$ (where the dimensions of $\theta$ and $\lambda$
are not necessarily the same). Then two facts hold true,

- Maximizing $L\left(\theta\right)$ wrt. $\theta$, that is, finding the MLE, $\hat{\theta}$, and then reparametrizing it, $g(\hat{\theta})$,
  yields the MLE of $\hat{\lambda}$. In short, $\hat{\lambda}=g\left(\hat{\theta}\right)$.
- Further, if $g$ has an inverse, maximizing $L\left(g^{-1}(\lambda)\right)$
  wrt. $\lambda$, that is, finding the MLE $\hat{\lambda}$ yields
  the same maximum as $\hat{\theta}$. So the MLE of $\theta$ is $\hat{\theta}=g^{-1}\left(\hat{\lambda}\right)$.

Splitting the invariance in these two sub-cases can seem a bit artificial,
but I find it useful since they represent two different use-cases
of re-parametrization.

#### In practice

The first use-case is where you somehow can identify the MLE for some
parameter, but you actually need a certain transformation of that
variable. For example you have an estimator, $\hat{\sigma},$ for the
parameter $\sigma$ in the normal distribution, but you are actually
interested in the MLE for the variance $\sigma^{2}$. Then you can
use the invariance principle and simply square the $\sigma$-MLE,
$\hat{\sigma^{2}}=(\hat{\sigma})^{2}$.

An example for the second use-case, is that you have a numerical algorithm,
like gradient descent or Newton-Raphson, to maximize the likelihood
function. Say, you want to estimate the parameter $\sigma^{2}$ from
a normal distribution. The parameter is strictly positive by definition,
but the numerical procedure doesn't allow you to make constraints.
Well, you can use the invariance property to set $\sigma^{2}=\exp(\lambda)$
and let the algorithm vary $\lambda$ instead of $\sigma^{2}$, this
way ensuring that $\sigma^{2}$ stays positive. The exponential is
bijective, but this is not strictly required. We could have used $\sigma^{2}=\lambda^{2}$
instead, which is not bijective. But using a bijection is more practical,
since we can go from $\sigma^{2}$ to $\lambda$ and back in a unique
fashion.

#### The formalities

To define the MLE of $\lambda$ more formally we need to define what is called the *profile likelihood
function* as,

$$L^{\ast}(\lambda)=\sup_{\theta\vert\lambda=g\left(\theta\right)}L\left(\theta\right).$$

So, for a given $\lambda$-value the profile likelihood value, is
the supremum over all $\theta$'s which ensure that $g\left(\theta\right)$
equals $\lambda$.

With the profile likelihood defined we can then define the MLE for
$\lambda$, denoted $\hat{\lambda}$, as the value which maximizes
$L^{\ast}\left(\lambda\right)$.

With these definitions in place the invariance of re-parametrization
boils down to,

$$
L^{\ast}\left(\hat{\lambda}\right)=L\left(\hat{\theta}\right)
$$

which can be proved by,

$$L^{\ast}\left(\hat{\lambda}\right)=\max_{\lambda}L^{\ast}\left(\lambda\right)=\max_{\lambda}\sup_{\theta\vert\lambda=g\left(\theta\right)}L\left(\theta\right)=\sup_{\theta}L\left(\theta\right)=\max_{\theta}L\left(\theta\right)$$

where I have assumed that $L\left(\theta\right)$ has a maximum.

If the re-parametrization is a bijection i.e. it is invertible, then
$L^{\ast}\left(\lambda\right)$ is simply $L(g(\theta))$ since each
$\theta$ uniquely maps to a $\lambda$, and hence the supremum over
``all'' $\theta$'s just collapses to the unique $L(\theta)$. So,
we get that,

\begin{align*}
L^{\ast}\left(\lambda\right) & =L\left(g\left(\theta\right)\right)\\
L^{\ast}\left(g^{-1}(\lambda)\right) & =L\left(\theta\right)
\end{align*}
and hence,

$$\hat{\theta}=g^{-1}\left(\hat{\lambda}\right).$$

References:

[Invariance property of MLE: what is the MLE of $\theta^2$ of normal, $\bar{X}^2$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77573/invariance-property-of-mle-what-is-the-mle-of-theta2-of-normal-barx2)

http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~dlunn/b8_02/b8pdf_6.pdf

http://www.stat.unc.edu/faculty/cji/lecture7.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Functional_invariance