# Does reparametriztion influence shape of likelihood function?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

i am working with likelihood function and i need 1 parameter to only have positive values. So when I transform this parameter (lets say $\sigma^2$) to $\psi_{\sigma^2}= \log \sigma^2$, how does it influence shape of likelihood function? Also when i do this, will results of maximization the likelihood change or they will stay same? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If your function $h$ that maps the old parameter $\sigma^2$ to the new parameter $\psi_{\sigma^2} = h(\sigma^2)$ is bijective, the result of maximum likelihood does not change (you get $\hat\psi_{\sigma^2}= h (\hat \sigma^2)$). The shape of the likelihood function changes if $h$ is not just a linear transformation. In your example, $h(.)=\log(.)$ is bijective and non linear. Although $\hat\psi$ then can be negative, the inverse $\hat\sigma^2=\exp(\hat\psi)$ is still positive.

See for example [this discussion where a non bijective transformation was proposed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333737/maximum-likelihood-is-not-re-parametrization-invariant-so-how-can-one-justify-u)